# Does Roslyn expose the compiler-generated yield transformations to the syntax trees?

Tags: yield, roslyn

The `yield` operator is implemented under the hood by the compiler generating a class that implements a state machine adhering to `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.

Given a Roslyn `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, it is possible to create the `ClassDeclarationSyntax` and generate a `MoveNext` method as the compiler usually does.  This transformation is necessary if one is writing a cross-compiler that is to support the `yield` operator -- one would first want to rewrite C# code to not use the yield operator and then let the cross-compiler take it from there.

However, it is clear that since Roslyn can compile C# code end-to-end, it must have the logic to perform this transformation in some fashion, and implementing this algorithm myself is pretty non-trivial.

My question: is that logic exposed in such a way that it is possible to leverage it to transform a given `MethodDeclarationSyntax` into the corresponding `ClassDeclarationSyntax` iterator declaration?  Or is it baked away at the `Emit` phase and thus unavailable when working among `SyntaxNode`s?

Comment: Depending on your goals, it could be simpler to translate the IL.

Comment: True, but my cross-compiler is a purely C#->JS compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Roslyn bits handles iterator methods as part of the code generation phase. Unfortunately, this phase is mostly opaque and uses an internal representation that is not exposed to the public API. The `Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.IteratorRewriter` internal class is where this is implemented, if you're in a mind to dig deeper into this.

For now, you'll have to implement this by yourself. However, the Roslyn team has hinted to a near-future update to the public CTP with substantial API changes, so cross your fingers and maybe the next version will have this feature.

Comment: Ah, thanks for info, especially the pointer to `IteratorRewriter`; it is exactly as you say, the logic written around a non-syntaxtree API. (in fact, a `BoundXXX` suite of classes that I will hope becomes public in the future).

Comment: I don't think the bound nodes are ever likely to become a public API, as we will want to change them as the compilers evolve. If you want a cross-compiler, you probably want to write your own "code generation" phase of the compiler, which comes after the phase that performs async lowering.

Comment: @NealGafter With you guys having open-sourced Roslyn, everything can be public APIs, right? Excellent work, by the way! :)

Comment: We're made "public" those parts that we're deliberately maintaining some level of compatibility with. As for the rest, you can think of it as a "public" API if you want, but don't be surprised when it changes out from under you.